# A kernel with less thread divergence

Tags: c++, cuda

Expected value of result = 8. Received value of result= 1; Can pin point what is wrong on this? Result should have the value of 8 but it is printing out the value of 1. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>`
#include <assert.h>
//define array size 8
#define ARRAY_SIZE 8
__global__ void vecAddKernel(int * A_d) {
//thread Index
unsigned int t = threadIdx.x;
    for (unsigned int stride = blockDim.x / 2; stride > 0; stride /= 2) {
    __syncthreads();
    if (t < stride)
        A_d[t] += A_d[t + stride];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    int A_h[ARRAY_SIZE];
   // initializing all values in A_h array to 1
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        A_h[i] = 1;
    }
    int * A_d, result;
   // reserving size array A_d of 8 in cuda
    cudaMalloc((void * * ) & A_d, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(A_d, A_h, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    vecAddKernel << < 1, ARRAY_SIZE / 2 >>> (A_d);
   Copy the first index of A_d to the result.
    cudaMemcpy( &result, &A_d[0], sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // outputting the value of result
    printf("Result = %d\n", result);
    //freeing the memory
    cudaFree(A_d);
}
```

Comment: I moved your problem statement before your code block. It's usually easier to digest code with some context.

Comment: @Chris Did you run the code to see what might I did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're getting `Result = 1`.

When I compile and run your code, I see `Result = 4`.  That's because the initial value of `stride` in the loop inside the kernel should be `blockDim.x` rather than `blockDim.x / 2` (the first iteration of the loop should add pairs of values separated by `ARRAY_SIZE / 2`, and `blockDim.x` is already `ARRAY_SIZE / 2`).

Replacing `blockDim.x / 2` with `blockDim.x` in the initializer of `unsigned int stride` renders the program correct.

If you're interested in performing array reductions like this, you might want to look at `__shfl_down` and the other shuffle functions introduced with Kepler: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/

Comment: It didn't work. Still saying result = 1 even though if I change kernel to start from BlockDim.x. Can you help

Comment: Perhaps one of the CUDA calls or the kernel launch is failing on your machine; you should add some error checking to your program.  Without making any code changes, you can quickly check if any of your CUDA API calls returns an error by running your program under `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: Yeah the reason was I was using nvcc --gpu-architecture=sm_30 test.cu so my kernel was not launching at all. Did some debugging to see the value of stride then finally worked. Thanks guys. @Thomas Foster I realized it was abvious I was chopping the array size by 2 and my stride should have start from blockDim.x rather than half of blockDim.x. Thanks for all your help.